# Limit VirtualBox guests to one network interface

Tags: networking, linux, virtualization

I have one Linux (Ubuntu) box and inside two Virtualbox guests (guest1 + guest2).

The host has two interfaces. (eth0 + eth1)

I need to define:

- Host uses only eth0
- Guest1 uses eth1
- Guest2 uses eth0

Is this possible?

What is the best way and have it secured that the traffic from each interface won't mix with each other.

Answer (score 0):

Unsure what this has to do with security versus a normal networking question so this is the simplest answer without getting into [virtual switching](http://networkstatic.net/open-vswitch-on-virtualbox/) on interfaces. Go to the settings of each machine, click on the network tab, then select "Bridged Adapater", then the specific adapter you want to assign to the guest hosts.

[image]

Above shows me selecting my ethernet card for networking.

[image]

Above shows me using my Wireless card for networking.

Comment: that part I know, but how to configure that the host uses eth0 only?

Answer (score 0):

[image]

With virtualbox, you can use the bridged adapter option. If you specify the network card for eth1 in guest1 settings page, guest1 will only have access to that single interface. Likewise for guest2. For the host, as long as you specify the default gateway as eth0, it should use only eth0.